# How to pass values between pages using thymeleaf in a spring MVC web application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a string variable that I create in a controller class and I want to print it in a jsp page using this

```
${time}
```

My code works if I don't use a thymeleaf view resolver, but if I do use one it doesn't work.

Here is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

     String thetime = "the time";
     model.addAttribute("time", thetime );

    return "home.jsp";
}
```

And my .jsp page

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Home</title>
   </head>
 <body>
 <h1>
   Hello world!  
 </h1>

 <P>  The time on the server is ${time}. </P>
 </body>
</html>
```

My thymeleaf resolver configuration:

```
@Bean 
 public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
    }
    @Bean 
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.setMessageSource(messageSource());

        return engine;
    }

    @Bean 
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        String[] vistas = {"*.html", "*.jsp"};
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setViewNames(vistas);
        resolver.setCache(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafSpringResource() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver vista = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        vista.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return vista;
    }
```

Is there a special notation to do this with thymeleaf?

Comment: Presumably, you aren't using a JSP with thymeleaf. What do you mean _don't work_? Be clear. What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

[Aesir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25635103/1677912) worked, but it wasn't necesary to change my .jsp page to a .html page. I just put this

```
<div th:text="${time}">TIME_PLACEHOLDER</div>
```

instead of just ${time}, and it worked without the HTML header that was suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your view resolver to be Thymeleaf but you trying to render JSP thats why it isn't working.

if you want that file converted to Thymeleaf format it needs to look like this (or approx) and the extension has to be .html not .jsp:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
     <title>Home</title>
   </head>
 <body>
 <h1>
   Hello world!  
 </h1>

 <P>  The time on the server is <div th:text=#{time}>TIME_PLACEHOLDER</div> </P>
 </body>
</html>
```